# G28 X does not home the hotend

Tags: marlin, homing, axis, ender3

I have a classic Ender 3 running Marlin-2.1.1 on a BTT SKR v1.3 board with TMC 2130 drivers. Wifi is connected with ESP3D on an ESP32-CAM board connected to a TFT port. The X endstop is on the left side.

When I send `G28` or `G28 X`, the hotend does not home properly.
Rather the hotend just moves a little to the right side (like 3 mm) and stops.
So if I keep on sending `G28 X`, the hotend just moves little by little to the right side.

[configuration files](https://files.fm/u/u4t8m3dna)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This indicates that the printer thinks the endstop is already triggered and is trying to back off to untrigger it, so that it can probe. If a minimal move to the right does not untrigger it, it gives up, assuming something is wrong with the endstop. Either your endstop switch is broken or it's not connected. A disconnected endstop switch will behave identically to one that's stuck down (open circuit).

Comment: Looking at the config file, the endstops are correctly configured (`XYZ_MIN_ENDSTOP_INVERTING`), so this answer is very plausible!

Comment: Correct Endstop was broken and a new replacement fixed the issue. Thank you all for your help.